# compare method violates its general contract exception java 7

Tags: java

Below code throws "Java Comparison method violates its general contract" when run on Java 6. But, on Java 7 it does not throw the same exception. what is the issue?. How can this code be modified to throw the exception on Java 7 as well?.

```
class ComparableScore implements Comparable<ComparableScore> {

    private int score;
    private String itemName;

    int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    void setScore(int i) {
        score = i;
    }

    String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    void setItemName(String str) {
        itemName = str;
    }

    public int compareTo(ComparableScore another) {
        if (score == another.getScore())
            return this.getItemName()
                    .compareToIgnoreCase(another.getItemName());
        else if ((score) > another.getScore())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        final ComparableScore other = (ComparableScore) o;

        if (score == other.getScore()
                && this.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(other.getItemName()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a class to be Comparable, it should have the behavior of comparison.  Aka, implement the comparteTo method of the interface it's implementing.

Comment: CompareTo method has been implemented in the above code.

Comment: Strange. We see this error on Java 7, not 6.

Answer (score 1):

This relates to this Java "bug" - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7193557

Except it is not a bug, it is a feature.  The new Java implementation of `sort` is telling you that your `compareTo` method is broken.

However, the bug report says that the exception is thrown on Java 7 not Java 6.  And checking the Java 6 source code confirms this.  That message doesn't appear in the source code for `Arrays.sort` which is where the sorting code is implemented in Java 6.

---

If your aim is to **break** your code in such a way that the exception occurs in Java 7, then:

- The exception is not being thrown at the moment because the contract is not being broken.  (Or at least, not in any obvious way that I can see ...)
- I don't know the precise conditions that will trigger the exception.
- Try some experiments (i.e. with different implementations of `compareTo` and `equals` that break the contract in different ways) or read the Java 7 source code to figure out for yourself what would cause it ... reproducibly.
- (And why, why, why would you want to do that???)

Comment: How to reproduce this exception in the code above when run on java 7.

Comment: @user901975 - I think you are confused.  The exception occurs on Java 7 not Java 6.

Comment: Yes, I am running this code on Java 7, but the exception is not thrown.

Comment: I'm saying that it can't be thrown on Java 6.  If it can, please provide the stack trace (and the full Java version / platform details) so that we can check it out.

Comment: I agree that exception can't be thrown on Java 6. I need the exception to thrown when above code is run on Java 7, which is not happening. How can the code be changed?.

Comment: So why did you say **THIS** given that you agree it is **NOT TRUE**?  *"Below code throws "Java Comparison method violates its general contract" when run on Java 6."*

Comment: Oh...it was a typo error, please ignore. BTW, is there a way to reproduce this exception on Java7.

Comment: No it is not a typo.  It is plainly a piece of false information.

Comment: @Mohan How can we reproduce an execption that is never thrown in the first place??