# Comparison method violates its general contract Exception

Tags: java, collections, comparator

Below is a block of code that results in exception as indicated,

Code :

```
Collections.sort( arrayList, new Comparator() 
{
    public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 )
    {
        TypeAdapterSort tas1 = ( TypeAdapterSort ) o1;
        TypeAdapterSort tas2 = ( TypeAdapterSort ) o2;
        if ( tas1.order < tas2.order )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
} );
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
                at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
                at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
                at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:426)
                at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:223)
                at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
                at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
                at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

When I run the same code as a standalone program, the issue never occurs. What is the issue with the comparator here? Is there a way to reproduce the issue in a standalone code?

This issue occurs only on Java 1.7 as there has been change in the implementation on Arrays.sort & Collections.sort. How to change the above code to avoid the issue?. Also, how to reproduce this issue in a standalone code?

Comment: if order is of type `Integer` you could return `tas1.order.compareTo(tas2.order)`

Comment: what do you mean by 'standalone program'? Or rather, what other option of running the code you are referring to?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: You already asked this question: [compare method violates its general contract exception java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897892/compare-method-violates-its-general-contract-exception-java-7)

Answer (score 3):

You need to return 0 on equal objects.

```
        if ( tas1.order < tas2.order ){
            return -1;
        } else if ( tas1.order == tas2.order ){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
```

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/1651233) more

Comment: But, why is the issue not reproduced when run as a standalone program where the value of intance variable order is maintained the same?

Comment: compare must be transitive. Your code isn't. So instead of working incorrectly, it states to you that your code is buggy. I think it is a very good behavior.

Comment: @baraky You might expect to write `tas1.order == tas2.order`, you surely missed the double "=" instead of ... assignment ;)